# Beautifull Soap. Split page using a value and not a tag

Tags: python

look please at this page:

https://mob.processotelematico.giustizia.it/proxy/index_mobile.php?version=1.1.11&platform=Android%208.0.0&uuid=137cd993b81df224&devicename=SM-G955F&token=c0ba723983c804d8eef1c9ee74cfcb99&azione=direttarg_siecic_mobile&tipoufficio=1&registro=PC&idufficio=0350330099&aaproc=2015&numproc=161&

Is a normal page that, with BeautifullSoap, I can use simply because it is a single block of data.

The problem is when I have this kind of page

https://mob.processotelematico.giustizia.it/proxy/index_mobile.php?version=1.1.11&platform=Android%208.0.0&uuid=137cd993b81df224&devicename=SM-G955F&token=c0ba723983c804d8eef1c9ee74cfcb99&azione=direttarg_siecic_mobile&tipoufficio=1&registro=PC&idufficio=0580910098&aaproc=2018&numproc=1&

As you see, in this page there are many block of data (all the same), but unfortunately, there are few tags. Only li and ul tags. The only way I have to intercept a block with respect to the next is through the value "Parti fascicolo". So not a tag, but a value.

How can I split the page into multiple blocks using the "Parti fascicolo" values? if I can split it, I can work it as I do for the first file.

I have seen that each "Parti del fascicolo" block has 7 ul blocks and inside it, there are one or more li tag. I sould to read in each "Parti del fascicolo" block, all the ul tag and inside it the li tag value.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have all list components in a list (e.g. obtained with `soup.find_all`), you can consume this list with a `while`-loop. Something like this:

```py
components = soup.find_all("li")
blocks = []
while components:
    current = components.pop(0)
    if current.text == "Parti fascicolo":
        blocks.append([current])
    else:
        blocks[-1].append(current)
```